# Bootstrap "btn-danger" class doesn't override "form-control" class

Tags: jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a form with bootstrap, which requires the "form-control" class on each input. I would like a readonly input to change to the "btn-danger" class on bad input to another field. However, when I add the "btn-danger" class to the input it does not override "form-control" on setting the background color except for when you are hovering over it. Removing the "form-control" class causes the input to change to the wrong size. Any idea why the background color is not overridden? Classes are supposed to cascade, right?

For example, if I have the following input:

```
<input id="test" class="form-control" readonly>
```

then this does not work like it should:

```
$('#test').addClass("btn btn-danger");
```

#### Edit:

This appears to a problem with the "form-control" style for readonly buttons. When I remove the readonly tag everything works fine. I suppose the readonly attribute enforces a grey background. How can I get around this?

Comment: You should post a more comprehensive code example. Are you trying validate form fields? You might want to check out [jQuery Validate](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) and this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/elektriheart/y3th2v5w/) if that's the case.

Comment: I'm doing my own validation. Try this, you'll see what I mean:

`<input type="text" class="form-control btn btn-danger" value="Test" readonly>`

Comment: OK, but how is that code related to your other fields as far as being a button and validation? I understand that it should "alert" a user if the input is incorrect but not how it's actually supposed to work is not clear in relation to where this reside in your form and what the purpose of the button element is.

Comment: All of that is not relevant; this is only a button styling question.

Comment: $('#test').addClass("btn btn-danger");

Comment: May be try .hide() and .show(); so use 2 inputs and hide the btn-danger onload and show the original one, when it receives a bad input hide the original input and show the btn-danger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got it. By default, attribute styles override class styles, so the background for a "readonly" button is grey no matter what class is added due to the following code:

```
.form-control[disabled],
.form-control[readonly],
fieldset[disabled] .form-control {
  background-color: #eee;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

However, "disabled" does not have the same behavior because a ".btn-danger[disabled]" class is explicitly defined:

```
btn-danger.disabled,
.btn-danger[disabled],
fieldset[disabled] .btn-danger,
.btn-danger.disabled:hover,
.btn-danger[disabled]:hover,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-danger:hover,
.btn-danger.disabled:focus,
.btn-danger[disabled]:focus,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-danger:focus,
.btn-danger.disabled.focus,
.btn-danger[disabled].focus,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-danger.focus,
.btn-danger.disabled:active,
.btn-danger[disabled]:active,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-danger:active,
.btn-danger.disabled.active,
.btn-danger[disabled].active,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-danger.active {
  background-color: #d9534f;
  border-color: #d43f3a;
}
```

The solution is to add a similar style for ".btn-danger[readonly]".

Answer (score 1):

```
$(#test).addClass("btn btn-danger");
```

That should have quotes around the test like this:

```
$("#test").addClass("btn btn-danger");
```

If that for some reason doesn't work, please post more of your code so we can understand more what the problem is and how to fix it.

**Update:** Try this to override the style of the readonly attribute.

```
input[readonly]
{
    /*your style here*/
}
```

Comment: Fixed that; it was a typo. See comments above. It is not related to any other code.

Comment: I found this in bootstrap.css. Still not sure why class "btn-danger" doesn't override it.

`.form-control[disabled],
.form-control[readonly],
fieldset[disabled] .form-control {
  background-color: #eee;
  opacity: 1;
}`

Comment: On your html page where you are linking the stylesheets, is the bootstrap.css file first or the custom CSS styles?